# Backup app stops working if not used for some time

Tags: backup

I'm using [SMS Backup & Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore) and it usually works just fine.

But, once in a while I notice it doesn't upload the files to my Google Drive anymore. And I find a lot of files waiting for upload (can be files of a month or two).

**Why is that happening, and how it can be changed?**

I have no need to enter the app on a regular basis, since everything is configured and I just want it to work.

**Notes:**

- It does backup locally, it just doesn't upload.
- It seems to me that it's something with the internet access while idle for a long time, but I don't know exactly the details of how it works (I remember reading something about that feature).
- At the hour it should backup to the cloud, the device is usually connected to the Wi-Fi.

**Thanks! Any idea would be appreciated!**

---

<sub>**Details:**

Android version: 7.0

Device: LG G5, stock rom, no root.</sub>

Comment: How old is the app version of Google Drive you use? Google sometimes slightly changes the backend API of their services which makes old app version no longer work.

Comment: I have the latest version from the Play Store (released on April 3, 2018), and I update all of my apps a few times a week (every time it suggest me to).

Comment: If it changes anything - it's not the first (nor the second) time it happens. It's been like this for a (long) while